# Google API Map of cities based on database

Tags: ajax, database, google-api

I'm wondering is there a possibility to create dynamic map of cities based on my database?
For example i have few cities in my db eg:

1   |   Warsaw
2   |   Cracov
3   |   Poznan
4   |   Poznan
5   |   Poznan
6   |   Warsaw
7   |   Berlin
8   |   Berlin

etc. This is based on registered users, and as you can see for example i have 2 users from Berlin, 2 from Warsaw, 1 from Cracov and 3 from Poznan. Now i'd like to count how many times unique city name is repeated. And i'd like to make an dynamic map based on this which will looks something like thad i've made in graphic editor

[image: mapa]

If count of city is bigger, then circle on it is bigger and it means that more people from that city where registered on my page. I'm looking for kind of that solution. It can me different and frpm different page but it has to be dynamic and change on every refresh, for example someone noew have registeres - whe i refresh it will add new city to map or if city exists before circle on it will be bigger.

Hope you understand me and you will help me ;)
regards
Darek

Comment: there is a similar solution in google analytics where you can see from where people were watching your page. And something like that i'm looking for

Comment: Do you want it to be realtime? And what server side language you are using?

Comment: server side language is php based on zend framework. And yes i want it to be real time if its possible. Or eventual updates should be in short interval of time